# Can "bind" do a reduce on a List monad?

Tags: functional-programming, monads

I know how to do the equivalent of Scheme's (or Python's) `map` and `filter` functions with the list monad using only the "bind" operation.

Here's some Scala to illustrate:

```
scala> // map
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6).flatMap {x => List(x * x)}                        
res20: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36)

scala> // filter    
scala> List(1,2,3,4,5,6).flatMap {x => if (x % 2 == 0) List() else List(x)}
res21: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 5)
```

and the same thing in Haskell:

```
Prelude> -- map
Prelude> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] >>= (\x -> [x * x])
[1,4,9,16,25,36]

Prelude> -- filter
Prelude> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] >>= (\x -> if (mod x 2 == 0) then [] else [x])
[1,3,5]
```

Scheme and Python also have a `reduce` function that's often grouped with `map` and `filter`. The `reduce` function combines the first two elements of a list using the supplied binary function, and then combines that result the the next element, and then so on. A common use to to compute the sum or product of a list of values. Here's some Python to illustrate:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [1,2,3,4,5,6])
21
>>> (((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)+6)
21
```

Is there any way to do the equivalent of this `reduce` using just the bind operation on a list monad? If bind can't do this on its own, what's the most "monadic" way to perform this operation?

If possible, please limit/avoid the use of syntactic sugar (ie: `do` notation in Haskell or sequence comprehensions in Scala) when answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the defining properties of the bind operation is that the result is still "inside" the monad¹. So when you perform bind on a list, the result will again be a list. Since the reduce operation² often results in something other than a list, it can't be expressed in terms of the bind operation.

In addition to that the bind operation on lists (i.e. concatMap/flatMap) only looks at one element at a time and offers no way of reusing the result of previous steps. So even if we're okay with getting the result wrapped in a single-element list, there's no way to do it just with monad operations.

---

¹ So if you have a type that allows you to perform no operations on it except the ones defined by the monad type class, you can never "break out" of the monad. That's what makes the IO monad works.

² Which is called fold in Haskell and Scala by the way.

Comment: I realize that bind can't "break out" of the monad. I was assuming there'd have to be an extra "unwrap" step that didn't use bind. That is, up until that unwrap step, the result of `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and some transformation of `+` would be `[21]`. Is there any way a reduce/fold could be implemented with bind plus one final "unwrap" operation?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that it's called "fold" in Haskell and Scala, by the way.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves Ah, I see. It's still not possible though. `concatMap/>>=` only looks at one element at a time and doesn't give you a method of accessing previous results, so there's no way to have an accumulator like you'd have in a fold.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I figured, but being very new to monads I wasn't sure if there was some clever trick I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

> If bind can't do this on its own, what's the most "monadic" way to perform this operation?

While the answer given by @sepp2k is correct, there is a way to do a `reduce`-like operation on a list monadically, but using the product or "writer" monad and an operation which corresponds to *distributing* the *product monad* over the *list functor*.

The definition is:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer.Lazy
import Data.Monoid

reduce :: Monoid a => [a] -> a
reduce xs = snd . runWriter . sequence $ map tell xs
```

Let me unpack:

- The `Writer` monad has a data type `Writer w a` which is basically a tuple (product) of a value `a` and "written" value `w`. The type of written values `w` must be a *monoid* where the *bind* operation of the `Writer` monad is defined something like:

  ```
      (w, a) >>= f = let (w', b) = f a in (mappend w w', b)
  ```

  i.e. take the incoming written value, and the result written value, and combine them using the binary operation of the monoid.
- The `tell` operation writes a value, `tell :: w -> Writer w ()`. Thus `map tell` has type `[a] -> [Writer a ()]` i.e. a list of monadic values where each element of the original list has been "written" in the monad.
- `sequence :: Monad m => [m a] -> m [a]` corresponds to a *distributive law* between lists and monads i.e. distribute the monad type over the list type; `sequence` can be defined in terms of bind as:

  ```
  sequence [] = return []
  sequnece (x:xs) = x >>= (\x' -> (sequence xs) >>= (\xs' -> return $ x':xs'))
  ```

  ([actually the implementation in `Prelude` uses `foldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Monad.html#sequence), a clue to the reduction-like usage)

  Thus, `sequence $ map tell xs` has type `Writer a [()]`
- The `runWriter` operation unpacks the `Writer` type, `runWriter :: Writer w a -> (a, w)`,
  which is composed here with `snd` to project out the accumulated value.

An example usage on lists of `Int`s would be to use the monoid instance:

```
  instance Monoid Int where
              mappend = (+)
              mempty = 0
```

then:

```
  > reduce ([1,2,3,4]::[Int])
  10
```

Comment: I doubt that this is something I'd ever use in practice, but an interesting/educational read! Thanks.